# Grafana by default displays the average of the metric value. Can this behavior be changed?

Tags: grafana

By default, the way Grafana displays unaltered values (those that don't have any functions applied to them) is to display the arithmetic average of the values it retrieves from the data source. For example, when zoomed out to a five-minute granularity, Grafana averages the one minute values together to display a single value for that 5-minute period. 
Can this behavior be changed so that something like a maximum or a sum is displayed instead of the average?